# How to run Task with Laravel spatie/async

Tags: laravel, parallel-processing

Hi I want to handle parallel process with async task here is my code on task:

```
$protected $arrayData;
$protected $services;
$protected $result;

public function __contruct(arrayData) 
{
}

public function configure()
{
   require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php',
   $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/app.php'
   $kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);
   $kernel->handle(...);
}
```

So, how can i run this on run like this

```
public function run()
{
   $user = new User();
   $services = new HandleServices();
   $services->run($user);
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function handleParallel()
{
    $pool = Pool::create();
    foreach($fileInfos as $fileInfo)
   {
      $pool[] = async(function() {
      return new Task($fileinfo);
    })
   }
    $result = $pool->await();
}
```

And return to $pool->await?
Now, it's return null for all protected.
Please help me.

Comment: `$protected $arrayData;` is invalid. So is `__contruct(arrayData)` (as well as misspelled). A Laravel job shouldn't need you to require the autoloader. This code should be throwing errors all over the place; can you share the *actual* code you're trying?

Comment: @ceejayoz When i run this package spatie/async with parallel, it's start from nothing. So i must be initialise laravel on this. I want to run parallel and get response. Queue or job laravel can't get response from this.

Answer (score 0):

You should not boot up laravel framework with spatie/async, read this: https://github.com/spatie/async/issues/97

Basically this package is not made to be used with laravel, the reason is that if you bootstrap the whole framework every time for every child process by using the config() method in a Task, its resource intensive and will affect your performance.

For laravel you should use [queue](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues) instead.

With laravel queue, the framework is booted up once when the queue worker starts, and then picks up jobs and processes them without having to boot it up again which is very fast.

If you boot up laravel every time a child process runs with spatie/async you loose the whole point of performance gains.

PS: you can still use this with laravel, but not using laravel's facades or build in features. Just doing some raw calculations, etc inside the async tasks, then no need to boot up the framework.